# How to fix pink borders in GTK+ 3?

Tags: themes, gnome, gtk

I have problem with standard gnome3 theme "Adwaita". How to fix it?

[image: im1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764856#7):

> Problem with pink borders occurs, when you have too new version of Adwaita installed on your system. In order to have always up to date version of Adwaita, I made symlinks from /usr/share/themes/Adwaita contents (without gtk-2.0 directory) to ~/.themes/Advaivium.

So, go to `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita` directory and make symlinks (right click, Make Link) of all content except `gtk-2.0` directory and copy all symlinks to `/home/yourusername/.themes/Advaivium` (`yourusername` is your username on computer).